# Exporting to PNG, PDF, JPEG not working in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, export

For whatever reason ArcGIS Pro has recently been unable to export to PNG,JPEG, or PDF layouts containing raster layers without arbitrarily cutting off bits of the raster.

Example below (the blue river portion in layout view crosses the frame without breaks):

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this? And if so did you find a work around. And no, before someone asks this is not data on an ArcGIS server (which is known to cause export issues).

Comment: Try rebuilding statistics and pyramids for the raster?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What were the precise and detailed steps that you performed to see the results that you have presented?

Comment: Have you tried lowering the DPI? Sometimes I find that helps when I get this problem.

Comment: This reminds me of an issue in ArcGIS 9.3, the answer then was to go to the advanced settings utility and allow ArcGIS more memory to export. I have also seen this sort of thing more recently when using a virtual raster or BIL raster format, the fix for that is to use a format like GeoTIFF or ERDAS IMG. I'd start with @Hornbydd suggestion, perhaps the pyramids are a bit funny, you could also try export the image to a different format, that will show you soon enough if your raster is corrupt.